# create a wav file from multiple wav files in delphi

Tags: delphi

I've a problem doing my finals project:

I'm having trouble with how to save multiple wav files into 1 wav file.

For example - I have 3 wav files which are the syllables of the word "hospital" :

`hos.wav`   `pi.wav`  and `tal.wav`

Each of those syllable wav files contains utterances of the syllables of the word "hospital" respectively.

My task is to merge those files so that the word hospital could be reproduced from those files. I then have to save the merged file to be a new wav file, let say `hospital.wav`.

I've done my first task, but not my second task.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Wave Audio Package](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-packages/waveaudio/) for this.
And [here](http://forum.delphiarea.com/viewtopic.php?t=72) is the implementation of a function to make a wave audio stream by merging several wave audio streams.

Comment: Thx a lot bro..
         now i'm still trying to implement the program..
         i'll send questions again if i get problems..